# Regex to find trailing letter in a string

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a SQL query in a string, it is dynamically built. Occasionally it will include a decimal in the form of `"1000M"`.

The `M` is always uppercase. So the string might look like this:

```
"3 sql stmts here 10009M some other 3 sql stmts here"
```

I would like to know if its possible to reliably and consistently remove the `M`. So the string would look like this:

```
"3 sql stmts here 10009 some other 3 sql stmts here"
```

I started considering regex:

```
[0-9][M]
```

This will match the number before `M` and `M` itself.

Id like to know if its possible using regex, unless there is a better way

Comment: You can remove it with `Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d+)M\b", "$1");` See [this demo](http://ideone.com/4Pgzd8)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does the `$1` do here?

Comment: I explained it in the answer.

Comment: The simple way is to use `(?<=\d)M` and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\d+)M\b", "$1");
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/4Pgzd8).

The `(\d+)` matches and *captures into Group 1* one or more digits, and `M\b` matches a `M` that is followed with a non-word character or at the end of the string.

With `$1` (a backreference to Group 1) we can access the contents that were matched with the first capturing group `(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a whitespace boundary, not a word boundary.

Find: `(?<=(?<!\S)\d+)M(?!\S)`
Replace: nothing